# Low voltage fans and speed controllers

Tags: pwm, motor-controller, fan

First time asking a question here, please excuse any failures of etiquette!

I have a number of these [5V fans](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0775ZM4DW) that I have used for small projects. Fully aware that I might be impacting their longevity, I have run them anywhere from 4V to 8.5V to achieve the desired effect and I have so "go-to" circuits to apply these voltages to them.

I decided that I should have a single go-to circuit that applies the higher voltage of 8.5V and uses this  [PWM speed controller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FLJ6ZHQ) to achieve the lower speeds.

However, I found that my fans now only work with a power supply voltage up to 5.5V and abruptly shut off above that -- they behave the same as if I was applying too low of a voltage. In addition, there is effectively no speed regulation. The fan is on at the very top end of the potentiometer (drawing about 220mA) and just suddenly cut off as I turn the knob down once I dip below about 90% of its mechanical range.

I wrote it off to getting faulty speed controllers as a lot of reviewers reported, but on a whim I hooked it up to this [12V fan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071WMHNG5) that I also had around. It works as expected! With the controller turned all the way up (I assume a 100% duty cycle), the fan comes on at 3.5V (drawing 50mA) and works as expected all the way up to 15V (drawing 220mA, I didn't test it above) and at its rated 12V (drawing 170mA @ 100% duty cycle) gives me very smooth linear speed control using about 60% of the range of the knob before cutting off.

Am I missing something about the specifications of these fans that I should be looking for before purchasing them? I was under the impression that all 2-wire fans were largely the same, which is clearly not the case.

Thank you for any guidance!

Comment: If you're operating it outside its specified operating conditions, what it does is unspecified.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, I appreciate that and it makes sense, but can you think of a reason why even at 5V I don't get any speed control? It just shuts off when I back off of 100% duty cycle in the slightest.

Comment: That would be speculation. But the PWM controller IC may not work at all outside its voltage range. Most ICs don't.

Comment: PWM on Hall sense self commutating BLDC fans are problematic with flyback V on internal caps and aliasing unless it has PWM input.  been there done that. Consider a 5W LDO ADJ with heatsink. Max PD is 50% at half speed

Comment: @BrianDrummond this would be inside its voltage range, which is 1.8V-15V DC

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, so these fans are not a good fit for PWM in their 2-wire configuration (without a dedicated PWM input)? Sounds reasonable (or configurations with PWM input wouldn't exist). I wonder why the 12V fan performed so well then.

Comment: You were lucky to avoid the pitfalls or may be not noticed

Comment: These are brushless fans so they must have controller circuits inside them. Brushless controller circuits aren't all the same.